# Digi S2B Modules, button interrupt routine

Tags: xbee, irq, codewarrior, isr

I'm designing an application using Freescale CodeWarrior IDE with Digi Extension. I've created samples application and used them. That worked quite fine but I had some problems with IRQ. If I use an IRQ component, I'm not always entering the interrup routine. I mean that when I press the button, I don't always enter the myButton_irq() function. 
Any idea why ? Do you have same issue ?

Now that I'm trying other application, the button reaction becomes less and less efficient...

Thanks in advance,

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this behavior in the default samples or after modifying the code?
Assuming you are using the XBIB boards, ensure that the pull-up resistor in the IRQ component is enabled (or place an external one).
Another typical error is that an application is getting stuck somewhere in an interrupt context, always ensure that you leave the interrupt routines as fast as you can.